# Allow acces on a website even with domain filtering set on

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube-api

I made a simple web app using the youtube api, it's basically just a simple search and show result:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos?alt=json-in-script&q=' + q,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        /* Show result */
    }
});
```

I don't have any problem with the code, however I'm curious how to bypass the domain filter that I set on for **youtube.com**. At first I thought doing a request via AJAX might do the trick since it's just running on the background. It's still caught by the domain filtering, I need help on how to make it working properly even if domain filtering is enabled.

This is the error on console (it points to the jquery.js ajax):
[image]

Any idea will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

---

This is the domain filtering I am talking about (on the router):
[image]

Comment: First of all, what domain filtering are you talking about? Secondly, that image doesn't show an error message (it shows an *error*, but the message is cut off).

Comment: From the router's point of view there's no difference between Ajax and "normal" URL requests.

Comment: To by pass the domain filtering, use a proxy server with a domain not blocked, seems logic after all, isn't it?!

Comment: I see thanks. But is there a web development technique or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you're asking this...

> How do I block access to YouTube while allowing access to YouTube?

Phrased like that, it sounds kind of silly.  And that's sort of the point.  You can't simultaneously *allow* and *disallow* the same thing.  The two options are mutually exclusive.  If your firewall is blocking web requests to that domain, then it's going to block all of them.

You *might* be able to get around the restriction by requesting the IP address directly instead of the domain name, but that's probably not a great solution.  Another idea might be to block only `www.youtube.com` and allow `gdata.youtube.com` in the firewall settings, if that's possible.  (Adjusting the firewall settings are kind of outside the scope of Stack Overflow, though.)

Comment: "How do I block access to YouTube while allowing access to YouTube?" I understood the opposite, isn't filtering option used to blocked domain in list? I understand: "How to access youtube when blocking it" which is still a silly question

Comment: I mean something like `How can I use properly/access my site that uses YouTube API when I'm blocking the youtube.com domain`.

Comment: @user3040235: You can't, that's the point.  If YouTube is blocked, then it's *blocked*.  Requests to that domain are not allowed.  So anything which relies on requests to that domain isn't going to work.

Comment: @user3040235 i guess the only solution is to proxify your request. Or ya, try to allow subdomain if you can

Comment: I see, sorry It's kinda silly but I'm just curious if there is a possible solution. Maybe by direct IP address is one solution. Thanks!

Comment: @user3040235 we are here mostly developers, maybe your question should be ask here instead: http://serverfault.com/  And i hope for security than your domain filtering is 'clever' enough to still not allow domain access using IP checking DNS